# Итеграция внутри thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Коллеги, добрый день.

Есть сайт с примером https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list

И мне не понятно место, где пишут

### However, we also need to use the itemStat variable to define which list element we’re referring to, as demonstrated in:

Если там итак идет итерация

```
<tr th:each="book, itemStat : *{books}">
```

почему мы не можем использовать

```
th:field="*{book.title}"
```

вместо

```
th:field="*{books[__${itemStat.index}__].title}"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Почитай [документацию](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status). Там более понятно описано, что такое itemStat

Comment: @notaProgrammer , комментарий в ни куда. Конечно я читал и мне понятно то, что там написано. Поэтому я и спрашиваю про данный случай. Ведь что book.title (где itemStat.index=0) , хоть books[__${itemStat.index}__].title, что будет равно books[0].title - это одинаково.

Comment: А Вы видели, что кроме переменной index есть еще first, last, even, odd (которые могут понадобиться для того, чтобы, допустим, добавить какой-то css класс для парных, не парных элементов, возможно выделить как-то первый элемент или Вы просто захотите показывать только парные элементы)

Comment: Уважаемый @notaProgrammer. Вопрос был задан не Зачем index в itemStat, а в том, почему нельзя было использовать в данном случае так?

Comment: А если просто book.title без *{}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, провел некий тест. Получается, для разных ситуаций либо нужно использовать iterStat, либо не нужно. Зависит от того list, Map, Object или еще что-то было передано.

В данном случае, в качестве th:object="${selectedProduct}" передан объект, который содержит в себе лишь List<> mapList;

```
th:field="*{product.productId}"                                 
th:field="*{mapList[__${iterStat.index}__].productId}"          
th:field="${mapList[__${iterStat.index}__].productId}"          
th:field="${__${product.productId}__}"                          
th:field="${product.productId}"                                 
th:field="${product.productId != null} ? ${product.productId} : ${product.enumName}"        

th:value="*{product.productId}"                                 
th:value="${mapList[__${iterStat.index}__].productId}"          
th:value="*{mapList[__${iterStat.index}__].productId}"          
th:value="${__#{product.productId}__}"                          
th:value="${product.productId}"                                 
th:value="${product.customName != null} ? ${product.productId} : ${product.enumName}"
```

Для меня подошло, чтобы форма отображала значение, но ее нельзя было изменять, вот такой вариант

```
 <input readonly type="text" th:field="*{mapList[__${iterStat.index}__].productId}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете не использовать `itemStat`.

Пример сделан для демонстрации того, как можно получить индекс элемента

Для **получения индекса** нужно использовать переменную `itemStat`, а вывод элемента через индекс, это просто демонстрация использования этого индекса

Comment: Добрый день. То есть можно использовать так?
   th:field="*{book.title}" или th:field="*{books[__${itemStat.index}__].title}" или так th:field="$books[0].title" ?